# AWS Athena - Queries of this type are not supported [basic query]

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I'm running the following query and I get the 'queries of this type are not supported'.

What am I doing wrong?

```
select 
t.pol_number,
t.pdb_id

from
static_filters T
where left(cast(t.pdb_id as string), 1) = '5'

limit 10
```

Both those fields are integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

athena knows nothing  of left so use use substr

you can look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/presto-functions.html) which functions are supported

```
select 
    t.pol_number,
    t.pdb_id
from
    static_filters t
where substr((cast(t.pdb_id as string), 1,1) = '5'
limit 10
```

still your query needs and `ORDER BY` without it  a limit makes not much sense